# JavaScript: event triggering

Tags: javascript

How would I go about developing cross-browser event triggering for mouse buttons (left, middle and right) in **plain-vanalla** JavaScript?

Comment: Um, why... you could just use jQuery and not reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I am fond of home-made wheels.

Comment: I don't know what all the fuss is about! You all shouldn't be so partial. Shocking!

Comment: Keep in mind, though you can trigger events, it only causes event handlers to be fired. For instance, triggering a `click` event on an `a` link won't open the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be strongly recommended you use a Javascript Library for this purpose.

Most popular being [JQuery](http://jquery.com) (recommended)

For additional libraries you can view the following [what-is-the-best-lightweight-javascript-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74048/what-is-the-best-lightweight-javascript-framework)

Do you have a valid reason for not using any libraries...?

Regards

Gordon

Comment: Please, stop asking that sort of questions, and better try answering mine.

Comment: Fair enough... in reply to your question, open the jquery source code and copy the "cross-browser event triggering" code and paste it into your javascript file. Its cross browser, its been written and you can pretend its home-made...

Comment: could you please show me which part of jQuery I should use and how to rebuild it so that I get exactly what I need. Thanks.

Comment: Ridiculous? What's so ridiculous? I asked gg not to demand a valid reason from me because that doesn't pertain to my question.

Comment: Sorry. Forget about it. Wrote this after I took the time to gather a few relevant links and saw that you accepted the "hey just copy jQuery's solution" answer. Which upset me a little after you wrote: I want to do it myself. btw. just copying the code and pretending it is home made would be a license violation too

Comment: He He!!! I am from Russia. A fat lot we care about license violations! =) But back to my business. I do not want just use what could/should be done myself. I study JS, so it is important for me to do things myself. Frameworks are good but they perhaps deprive me of understanding the real core of JS. And after all, I just don't need the whole libraly to do the triggering, do I?

Comment: I was kidding about copying the code :) sarcasm, fail... :) I understand you would like to do this yourself, but I think you will find its a great amount of work with very little reward. Rather spend your effort on learning the good parts of Javascript, not the crappy dom aspect of it. JQuery is simply a tool that allows you focus on the good aspects and not worry about browser compatibility etc. Douglas Crockford has a really good book on Javascript called "JavaScript: The Good Parts". It's worth the read.

P.S. jitter's answer should be marked as the correct one...

Answer (score 4):

A few starting points

- [`document.createEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createEvent)
- [`element.dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent)
- [`fireEvent` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536423(VS.85).aspx)
- [`createEventObject` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536390(VS.85).aspx)
- [event.simulate.js](http://github.com/kangax/protolicious/blob/5b56fdafcd7d7662c9d648534225039b2e78e371/event.simulate.js)
- A look into how known big Javascript Frameworks do it (e.g. [`jQuery`](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js))
- And don't forget

  - grab a cup of coffee (or better two)
  - be ready to get many headaches
  - be ready to encounter subtle bugs which will make you want to rip your hear out
  - to make it crossbrowser you will need to do a lot(!) of testing

Comment: Very nice links. Not sure why this would not have been accepted (compared to the one that was). I just want to point out (to @David as well) that point #6 does not utilize any of points 1-5. @David: you're in for a big surprise when you see the approach jQuery took in simulating events.

Comment: Upped you and commented that yours should be accepted as the correct one. More in scope with question.